# How do we treat conditional expectations when using the law of iterated expectation?

Tags: probability

As per the title, I was wondering if someone could provide an explanation for the way in which we treat conditional expectations in the law of iterated expectations.

Specifically, why do we write this:

$$\mathbb{E} [X|Y]  = \mathbb{E}_{Z|Y}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y,Z) |Y ] $$

Instead of

$$\mathbb{E} [X|Y]  = \mathbb{E}_{Z}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y,Z)] $$

Is there a intuitive way to explain why we ought to condition the variable $Z$ on $Y$ when taking the outer expectation?

Comment: What does the subscript on the expectation mean?

Comment: @JasonSwanson to average with respect to that RV’s law, presumably.

Comment: @JasonSwanson It is an old notation, sometimes still used in statistics or physics texts, but depreciated because it causes more confusion than clarity.  They are training wheels meant as a reminder that the outer expectation is an integration(or summation) with respect to the probability measure of $Z$ conditioned over $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index $Z\mid Y$ is a notational reminder that the outer expectation will be made with respect to the probability measure of $Z$ conditioned over $Y$

$$\Bbb E(X\mid Y)=\Bbb E_{Z\mid Y}(\Bbb E(X\mid Y,Z)\mid Y)
\\ \int_A X(\omega)~\mathrm dP_{X\mid Y}(\omega)=\iint_A X(\omega)~\mathrm d P_{X\mid Y,Z}(\omega)~\mathrm d P_{Z\mid Y}(\omega)\qquad\text{for any }A\in\sigma(Y)$$

This older notation is depreciated, and the standard is currently to just express it as $$\Bbb E(X\mid Y)=\Bbb E(\Bbb E(X\mid Y,Z)\mid Y)$$

Comment: But is there an explanation why we have to condition $Z$ over $Y$? Why must this be considered in the outer expectation?

Comment: It is based on the law of total probability.  For continuous, real-valued random variables we have : $$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=\int_\Bbb R f_{X\mid Y,Z}(x\mid y, z)~f_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y)~\mathsf d z$$